# C Using Mutexes & Semaphores to create a Blocking Stack using Threads

Tags: c, thread-safety, pthreads, mutex, semaphore

there, I've written a program to create a Blocking Stack that observes thread safety. 
I have utilised functions implemented within the Stack.c file to carry out the Blocking functions in the BlockingStack.c file, and I have used mutexes & semaphores for this purpose.
However, when I am trying to pop off an empty stack, even if I sleep & push the elements after, it is still stuck waiting infinitely & I am not sure what I am doing wrong & I am not sure how to test my implementation as it just keeps on waiting forever & passing sometimes & failing other times. 
Any guidance would be very appreciated.

Here is my code for the BlockingStack:

Blocking Stack:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include "BlockingStack.h"
#include "Stack.h"
#include <pthread.h>


BlockingStack *new_BlockingStack(int max_size) {
    BlockingStack *newBlockingStack = malloc(sizeof(BlockingStack)*max_size);
    if (newBlockingStack == NULL){
        return false;
    }
    newBlockingStack->top = -1;
    newBlockingStack->capacity = max_size;
    newBlockingStack->size = 0;
    newBlockingStack->element = new_Stack(max_size);
    pthread_mutex_init(&newBlockingStack->mutex, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_init(&newBlockingStack->clearMutex, NULL);
    sem_init(&newBlockingStack->items,0,0);
    sem_init(&newBlockingStack->space,0, newBlockingStack->capacity);
    return newBlockingStack;
}


bool BlockingStack_push(BlockingStack* this, void* element) {
    if (element == NULL){
        return false;
    }
    else {
        sem_wait(&this->space);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&this->mutex);
        Stack_push(this->element, element);
        sem_post(&this->items);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&this->mutex);
        return true;
    }
}

void* BlockingStack_pop(BlockingStack* this) {
    sem_wait(&this->items);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&this->mutex);
    void* element = Stack_pop(this->element);
    sem_post(&this->space);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&this->mutex);
    return element;
}


int BlockingStack_size(BlockingStack* this) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&this->mutex);
    int size = Stack_size(this->element);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&this->mutex);
    return size;
}


bool BlockingStack_isEmpty(BlockingStack* this) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&this->mutex);
    bool isEmpty;
    if(!Stack_isEmpty(this->element)){
        isEmpty = false;
    }
    else {
        isEmpty = true;
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&this->mutex); 
    return isEmpty;
}


void BlockingStack_clear(BlockingStack* this) {
    // int size = BlockingStack_size(this);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&(this->mutex));
    Stack_clear(this->element);
    while (sem_trywait(&(this->items)) != -1){
        // sem_wait(&(this->items));
        sem_post(&(this->space));
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&(this->mutex));
}


void BlockingStack_destroy(BlockingStack* this) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&this->mutex);
    Stack_destroy(this->element);
```

My code for the Stack:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "Stack.h"


Stack *new_Stack(int max_size) {
    Stack* stack = malloc(sizeof(Stack)); 
    stack->capacity = max_size; 
    stack->top = -1; 
    stack->size = 0;
    stack->element = malloc(sizeof(void*)*max_size); 
    return stack;
}


bool Stack_push(Stack* this, void* element) {
    if ((this->top >= this->capacity-1) || element == NULL){
        return false;
    }
    this->top++;
    this->element[this->top] = element;
    this->size++;
    return true;
}


void* Stack_pop(Stack* this) {
    if (!Stack_isEmpty(this)){
        this->size--;
        return this->element[this->top--];      
    }
    return NULL;
}


int Stack_size(Stack* this) {
    return this->size; 
}


bool Stack_isEmpty(Stack* this) {
    if(this->top == -1 && this->size == 0){
        return true;
    }
        return false;
}

void Stack_clear(Stack* this) {
    this->top = -1;
    this->size = 0;
}

void Stack_destroy(Stack* this) {
    free(this->element);
    free(this);
}
```

And finally, the set of tests that should run the BlockingStack:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include "BlockingStack.h"
#include "myassert.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>


#define MAX_STACK_SIZE 20

/*
 * The stack to use during tests
 */
static BlockingStack *stack;

static int success_count = 0;


static int total_count = 0;


void setup(){
    stack = new_BlockingStack(MAX_STACK_SIZE);
    total_count++;
}


void teardown(){
    BlockingStack_destroy(stack);
}

void runTest(int (*testFunction)()) {
    setup();

    if (testFunction()) success_count++;

    teardown();
}

void *threadPush(void *arg){
    void *result = (void*) BlockingStack_push(stack, arg);
    pthread_exit(result);
}

void *threadPop(){
    void * result = (void*) BlockingStack_pop(stack);
    pthread_exit(result);
}

void *threadClear(){
    BlockingStack_clear(stack);
    return 0;
}


int newStackIsNotNull() {
    assert(stack != NULL);
    return TEST_SUCCESS;
}

int newStackSizeZero() {
    assert(BlockingStack_size(stack) == 0);
    return TEST_SUCCESS;
}

int checkEmpty(){
    assert(BlockingStack_isEmpty(stack));
    return TEST_SUCCESS;
}

int push(){
    int x = 5;
    void*pointer = &x;
    assert(BlockingStack_push(stack, pointer));
    return TEST_SUCCESS;
}

int pushAndPop(){
    int x = 5;
    void *ptr = &x;

    pthread_t thread1, thread2;
    void *tr1, *tr2;

    pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, threadPush, ptr);
    pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, threadPop, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread1, &tr1);
    pthread_join(thread2, &tr2);
    assert(BlockingStack_size(stack) == 0);
    return TEST_SUCCESS;
}

int pushAndPopMultipleThreads(){
    int size = 100;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        pthread_t thread1, thread2; 
        void*ptr = &i;
        pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, threadPush, ptr);
        pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, threadPop, NULL);
        pthread_join(thread1, NULL);
        pthread_join(thread2, NULL);
    }
    assert(BlockingStack_isEmpty(stack));
    return TEST_SUCCESS; 
}


int pushAndPopMultipleThreadsAndCheckSize(){
    int size = 100;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        pthread_t thread1, thread2; 
        void*ptr = &i;
        pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, threadPush, ptr);
        pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, threadPop, NULL);
        pthread_join(thread1, NULL);
        pthread_join(thread2, NULL);
    }
    assert(BlockingStack_size(stack)==0);
    return TEST_SUCCESS; 
}


int pushEmpty(){

    int x = 5;
    void *element = &x; 
    pthread_t thread1, thread2;
    void *result;

    pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, threadPop, NULL);
    sleep(3);
    pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, threadPush, element);

    pthread_join(thread1, &result);
    pthread_join(thread2, NULL);
    assert(BlockingStack_pop(stack) == element);

    return TEST_SUCCESS;
}

int populateFullyThenClear(){
    pthread_t thread1, thread2, thread3;
    void *tr1, *tr3;

    for (int i = 0; i <= MAX_STACK_SIZE; i++){
        pthread_t tr = 0;
        void*ptr = &i;
        pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, threadPush, ptr);
        pthread_join(tr, NULL);
    }

    int check = MAX_STACK_SIZE+1;
    void*ptr1 = &check;
    pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, threadPush, ptr1);
    assert(BlockingStack_size(stack) == MAX_STACK_SIZE);

    pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, threadClear, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread2, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread1, &tr1);
    assert(BlockingStack_size(stack) == 1);

    pthread_create(&thread3, NULL, threadPop, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread3, &tr3);
    assert(((int)tr3)==(MAX_STACK_SIZE+1));

    return TEST_SUCCESS;
}


int main() {
    runTest(newStackIsNotNull);
    runTest(newStackSizeZero);
    runTest(checkEmpty);
    runTest(push);
    runTest(pushAndPop);
    runTest(pushAndPopMultipleThreads);
    runTest(pushAndPopMultipleThreadsAndCheckSize);

}
```

Comment: Use a debugger and examine the state of the stack to see what the values are at that point. That will more than likely point to where the problem lies.

Comment: Your sequencing is wrong.  The semaphore signaling sbould be outside the mutex lock/push/unlock.

Comment: `assert(BlockingStack_pop(stack) == element);` That could be the problem. The `pushEmpty` test does a push and a pop leaving an empty stack. Hence `BlockingStack_pop` will block.

Comment: The data is more important than the code.  What is 'BlockingStack'?   We sbould not have to guess:(

Comment: In 'populateFullyThenClear', you pass the address of the loop counter to pthread_create.  You get away with that by joining inside the loop and so forcing the tbreads to run serially, but you should be aware that the practice is hazardous.

Comment: Many of your thread functions do not conform to the signature required by pthread_create().

Comment: The loop in 'populateFullyThenClear' tries to push one more item than the stack can hold, resulting in the last thread, and so the whole lot, blocking forever because of the join.

Comment: 'pushAndPopMultipleThreads' runs only two threads at a time because of the joins.  Your entire design is join-heavy and no, that is not a good thing:)

Comment: I will try to post a more comprehensive answer when I wake up tomorrow.  You have obviously tried very hard to devise a test harness and deserve better, but I'm 'tired and emotional' ATM:)  Bed.....